# US: Can a website with a contact form but no privacy policy get sued

Tags: united-states, internet, privacy, business

I've seen business websites where the founders are literally lawyers, and their websites do not have a privacy policy. Their websites do have a contact form where users enter their email, message, name, etc. I get that nobody is going to sue a website that has 10 monthly traffic regardless, but these businesses have like millions in revenue and deal with rich or high-profile clients. I feel like it's too much of a rookie mistake? They also don't have a terms of service.

Comment: There's nothing on the website that forces you to provide your info. Can you go up to a house, put your private information into their mailbox, and then sue them for having your private information? It's different if you're paying for services and then they require the private info, but that's not what is happening here.

Comment: Not all websites offer an interactive service. A contact form alone is no different than a directory listing or business card and probably doesn't call for a privacy policy. Also, for lawyers as one example, the privacy policy is implied-in-law, even if not formally stated.

Comment: Privacy-wise, the form is even *less* invasive than simply listing an email address you can contact. When you send an email, you expose your real email address. In the web form you can enter a fake one if you just want to deliver a message and don't need to hear back.

Comment: Technically, the website does not store your information: the contact form sends an e-mail to the e-mail box of the website. It acts like a post box.